# Escape colon (`:`) in object_delete key in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variant

I have a variant type that contains a key with a colon `:` in the name which is sometimes nested `{"object":{"department:custom": "value}}`. I want to remove these keys from the variant (using `object_delete`). How can I do this?

Input:

```sql
select 
OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('object', OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('team_name:custom', 'some_value', 'key', 'value')) 
as examples from dual
union all
select 
OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('team_name:custom', OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('team_name:key', 'some_value'), 'object', OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('key', 'value')) 
as examples from dual;
```

Desired Output:

```
EXAMPLES
{   "object": {     "key": "value"   } }
{   "object": {     "key": "value"   } }
```

**Edit:** There is more than one key/value pair that I would like to keep, and the number of keys to keep varies and is not known in advance. What is known is that all keys containing `:` (and their children) are safe to remove.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this with `remove_object`, especially as you want to run this in a recursive way.

An alternative with a JS UDF:

```sql
create or replace function remove_colonned_keys(X variant)
returns variant
language javascript
as
$$
function remove_colonned_keys(obj) {
    if (typeof obj !== 'object' || obj === null) {
        return obj;
    }

    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        return obj.map(item => remove_colonned_keys(item));
    }

    const newObj = {};

    for (const key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && !key.includes(':')) {
            newObj[key] = remove_colonned_keys(obj[key]);
        }
    }

    return newObj;
}
```

For example:

```sql
return remove_colonned_keys(X);
$$;

with data as (
    select 
    OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('object', OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('team_name:custom', 'some_value', 'key', 'value')) 
    as e from dual
    union all
    select 
    OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('team_name:custom', OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('team_name:key', 'some_value'), 'object', OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('key', 'value')) 
    as examples from dual
)

select *, remove_colonned_keys(e)
from data
```

[image]

Comment: Hm, how does recursion enter this problem? If I have an `object` like `{"a":{"b":{"c":value"}}}` then I can access `value` via `a:b:c`. Is it not possible to do a similar thing with `remove_object` or another function that's part of Snowflake's SQL flavor?

Comment: I did my best. It's recursive because it has many levels.